# Display a specific item in QcomboBox at start up

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox

I have a `QcomboBox` with some items in it. When Widget starts up and display first item from `QcomboBox`. How could `QcomboBox` be forced to display third item `( Index(2))` in the list by start up?

[image]

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui

class combo(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(combo, self).__init__(parent)

        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.cb = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.cb.addItems(["1", "2", "3","4"])
        layout.addWidget(self.cb)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = combo()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current item can be set with setCurrentIndex().

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui

class combo(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(combo, self).__init__(parent)

        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.cb = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.cb.addItems(["1", "2", "3","4"])
        self.cb.setCurrentIndex(2)              # <---
        layout.addWidget(self.cb)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = combo()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]